# iPhone Core Data - How to remove NSManagedObject from context?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

```
CustomManagedObject *newObject = (CustomManagedObject *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Substation" inManagedObjectContext:[[DatabaseHelper instance] context]];
```

I make a new object, using the line above. However sometimes i dont want to save that object to permanent data store, i just want to remove it from context. Is there some kind of method like removeObject: object fromContext: context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the documentation? The method is called `deleteObject`:

```
[[[DatabaseHelper instance] context] deleteObject:newObject];
```

Comment: `Specifies an object that should be removed from its persistent store when changes are committed.` He wants to remove the object from the context, but not mark it for deletion. This is what `deleteObject:` does

Comment: @itsthejb You missed the paragraph that follows: "If object has not yet been saved to a persistent store, it is simply removed from the receiver."

Comment: Ok, true. In this use case I would still recommend using a temporary "scratch" context. The problem with creating objects in a main context is that they will be saved to the store unless you can carefully balance creating objects and deleting them. Unfortunately `NSMOC` doesn't have any kind of *prune* feature